# aspectJ in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, aspectj

I want to write simple example using aspectJ in intelliJ. And... i can't.

I can't find any tutorial that shows step by step what and how i should do.

I can't find any example with working code.

Can someone help me with this? Any link, or simple how to? One class with main, and one aspect.

intellij 9.0.2, with aspectj weaver 2.05

Comment: did you achieve your goal, cause with idea 10, i'm having some issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're highly advised to try [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/~roman.shevchenko/AspectJ+Support+Plugin) plugin :)